# Take screenshot of another X session

Tags: ubuntu, desktop, screenshot

User A is using Ubuntu desktop. I want to SSH remotely (as User A) and take a screenshot of the desktop from the terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very quick google search shows up a lot of answers for how to do this.

Most of them are something like this command:

```
xwd -out screenshot.xwd -root -display :0.0
```

For example: https://superuser.com/questions/224875

Answer (score 1):

Install `scrot`, and run the following command line when logged in remotely via `ssh` (in Ubuntu desktop 18.04.1 LTS),

```
DISPLAY=:0 scrot
```

and the dumpfile will be written in the current directory (in the server), like

```
2019-02-09-214843_1920x1080_scrot.png
```